# How to use numpy to get the cumulative count by unique values in linear time?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the following lists `short_list` and `long_list`

```
short_list = list('aaabaaacaaadaaac')
np.random.seed([3,1415])
long_list = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters),
                     (10000, 2))
).sum(1).tolist()
```

How do I calculate the cumulative count by unique value?

I want to use numpy and do it in linear time.  I want this to compare timings with my other methods. It may be easiest to illustrate with my first proposed solution

```
def pir1(l):
    s = pd.Series(l)
    return s.groupby(s).cumcount().tolist()

print(np.array(short_list))
print(pir1(short_list))

['a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'c' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'd' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'c']
[0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9, 10, 11, 1]
```

I've tortured myself trying to use `np.unique` because it returns a counts array, an inverse array, and an index array.  I was sure I could these to get at a solution.  The best I got is in `pir4` below which scales in quadratic time.  Also **note** that I don't care if counts start at 1 or zero as we can simply add or subtract 1.

Below are some of my attempts (none of which answer my question)

```
%%cython
from collections import defaultdict

def get_generator(l):
    counter = defaultdict(lambda: -1)
    for i in l:
        counter[i] += 1
        yield counter[i]

def pir2(l):
    return [i for i in get_generator(l)]
```

---

```
def pir3(l):
    return [i for i in get_generator(l)]

def pir4(l):
    unq, inv = np.unique(l, 0, 1, 0)
    a = np.arange(len(unq))
    matches = a[:, None] == inv
    return (matches * matches.cumsum(1)).sum(0).tolist()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with ```pir2``` - it makes a single pass over the list??

Comment: @wwii I like `pir2`!  It's the best I've found.  I just imagined that a single pass using numpy slicing would be faster.  I can't compare timings if I can't figure out a method.

Comment: Note that a solution that uses `numpy.unique` is O(n*log(n)), because the current implementation of `numpy.unique` sorts its argument.

Comment: You might be able to shave a bit off ```pir2``` by ditching the generator function and list comprehension and just iterate over the list, add each item to the counter then append the counter value to a list which you return.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser ty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using custom grouped range creating function and `np.unique` for getting the counts -

```
def grp_range(a):
    idx = a.cumsum()
    id_arr = np.ones(idx[-1],dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[idx[:-1]] = -a[:-1]+1
    return id_arr.cumsum()

count = np.unique(A,return_counts=1)[1]
out = grp_range(count)[np.argsort(A).argsort()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [117]: A = list('aaabaaacaaadaaac')

In [118]: count = np.unique(A,return_counts=1)[1]
     ...: out = grp_range(count)[np.argsort(A).argsort()]
     ...: 

In [119]: out
Out[119]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  0,  3,  4,  5,  0,  6,  7,  8,  0,  9, 10, 11,  1])
```

For getting the `count`, few other alternatives could be proposed with focus on performance -

```
np.bincount(np.unique(A,return_inverse=1)[1])
np.bincount(np.fromstring('aaabaaacaaadaaac',dtype=np.uint8)-97)
```

Additionally, with `A` containing `single-letter` characters, we could get the count simply with -

```
np.bincount(np.array(A).view('uint8')-97)
```

Comment: I've added an answer with some updated information if you're interested.

Comment: There is something amiss about your solution.  I have to think through it again and see what's wrong.  But I'm getting inaccurate results.

Comment: This code is incorrect. Should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

## setup

```
short_list = np.array(list('aaabaaacaaadaaac'))
```

## functions

- `dfill` takes an array and returns the positions where the array changes and repeats that index position until the next change.

  ```
  # dfill
  # 
  # Example with short_list
  #
  #    0  0  0  3  4  4  4  7  8  8  8 11 12 12 12 15
  # [  a  a  a  b  a  a  a  c  a  a  a  d  a  a  a  c]
  #
  # Example with short_list after sorting
  #
  #    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12 13 13 15
  # [  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  b  c  c  d]
  ```
- `argunsort` returns the permutation necessary to undo a sort given the `argsort` array.  The existence of this method became know to me [via this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242285/2336654).  With this, I can get the `argsort` array and sort my array with it.  Then I can undo the sort without the overhead of sorting again.
- `cumcount` will take an array sort it, find the `dfill` array.  An `np.arange` less `dfill` will give me cumulative count.  Then I un-sort

  ```
  # cumcount
  # 
  # Example with short_list
  #
  # short_list:
  # [ a  a  a  b  a  a  a  c  a  a  a  d  a  a  a  c]
  # 
  # short_list.argsort():
  # [ 0  1  2  4  5  6  8  9 10 12 13 14  3  7 15 11]
  #
  # Example with short_list after sorting
  #
  # short_list[short_list.argsort()]:
  # [ a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  b  c  c  d]
  # 
  # dfill(short_list[short_list.argsort()]):
  # [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12 13 13 15]
  # 
  # np.range(short_list.size):
  # [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
  #
  # np.range(short_list.size) - 
  #     dfill(short_list[short_list.argsort()]):
  # [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  0  0  1  0]
  # 
  # unsorted:
  # [ 0  1  2  0  3  4  5  0  6  7  8  0  9 10 11  1]
  ```
- `foo` function recommended by @hpaulj using `defaultdict`
- `div` function recommended by @Divakar (old, I'm sure he'd update it)

## code

```
def dfill(a):
    n = a.size
    b = np.concatenate([[0], np.where(a[:-1] != a[1:])[0] + 1, [n]])
    return np.arange(n)[b[:-1]].repeat(np.diff(b))

def argunsort(s):
    n = s.size
    u = np.empty(n, dtype=np.int64)
    u[s] = np.arange(n)
    return u

def cumcount(a):
    n = a.size
    s = a.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    i = argunsort(s)
    b = a[s]
    return (np.arange(n) - dfill(b))[i]

def foo(l):
    n = len(l)
    r = np.empty(n, dtype=np.int64)
    counter = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(n):
        counter[l[i]] += 1
        r[i] = counter[l[i]]
    return r - 1

def div(l):
    a = np.unique(l, return_counts=1)[1]
    idx = a.cumsum()
    id_arr = np.ones(idx[-1],dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[idx[:-1]] = -a[:-1]+1
    rng = id_arr.cumsum()
    return rng[argunsort(np.argsort(l))]
```

## demonstration

```
cumcount(short_list)

array([ 0,  1,  2,  0,  3,  4,  5,  0,  6,  7,  8,  0,  9, 10, 11,  1])
```

## time testing

### code

```
functions = pd.Index(['cumcount', 'foo', 'foo2', 'div'], name='function')
lengths = pd.RangeIndex(100, 1100, 100, 'array length')
results = pd.DataFrame(index=lengths, columns=functions)

from string import ascii_letters

for i in lengths:
    a = np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters), i)
    for j in functions:
        results.set_value(
            i, j,
            timeit(
                '{}(a)'.format(j),
                'from __main__ import a, {}'.format(j),
                number=1000
            )
        )

results.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: I need to research a bit more maybe on this and see if there's anymore improvement possible, but this looks good!

Comment: Why `kind='mergesort'`? Is it required that the sort is stable?

Answer (score 4):

Besides `defaultdict` there are a couple of other counters.  Testing a slightly simpler case:

```
In [298]: from collections import defaultdict
In [299]: from collections import defaultdict, Counter
In [300]: def foo(l):
     ...:     counter = defaultdict(int)
     ...:     for i in l:
     ...:         counter[i] += 1
     ...:     return counter
     ...: 
In [301]: short_list = list('aaabaaacaaadaaac')
In [302]: foo(short_list)
Out[302]: defaultdict(int, {'a': 12, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
In [303]: Counter(short_list)
Out[303]: Counter({'a': 12, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
In [304]: arr=[ord(i)-ord('a') for i in short_list]
In [305]: np.bincount(arr)
Out[305]: array([12,  1,  2,  1], dtype=int32)
```

I constructed `arr` because `bincount` only works with ints.

```
In [306]: timeit np.bincount(arr)
The slowest run took 82.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.63 µs per loop
In [307]: timeit Counter(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.6 µs per loop
In [308]: timeit foo(arr)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.49 µs per loop
```

I'm guessing it would hard to improve on `pir2` based on default_dict.

Searching and counting like this are not a strong area for `numpy`.

Comment: these all return the final counts.  each of my functions return a list or array of equal length as the original where each element in the returned list is the count of the corresponding element so far in the source list.  For straight counts, we numpy also has `np.unique(short_list, return_counts=True)[1]`

Comment: Yes, I chose not to take that extra step in the comparison.  It was easier that way.

Comment: I've added an answer with some updated information if you're interested.