# Transform a set of numbers in numpy so that each number gets converted into a number of other numbers which are less than it

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Consider a set of numbers:

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: x = np.array([np.random.random() for i in range(10)])

In [10]: x
Out[10]: 
array([ 0.62594394,  0.03255799,  0.7768568 ,  0.03050498,  0.01951657,
        0.04767246,  0.68038553,  0.60036203,  0.3617409 ,  0.80294355])
```

Now I want to transform this set into another set `y` in the following way: for every element `i` in `x`, the corresponding element `j` in `y` would be the number of other elements in `x` which are less than `i`. For example, the above given `x` would look like:

```
In [25]: y
Out[25]: array([ 6.,  2.,  8.,  1.,  0.,  3.,  7.,  5.,  4.,  9.])
```

Now, I can do this using simple python loops:

```
In [16]: for i in range(len(x)):
    ...:     tot = 0
    ...:     for j in range(len(x)):
    ...:         if x[i] > x[j]: tot += 1
    ...:     y[i] = int(tot)
```

However, when length of `x` is very large, the code becomes extremely slow. I was wondering if any numpy magic can be brought to rescue. For example, if I had to filter all the elements less than `0.5`, I would have simply used a Boolean masking:

```
In [19]: z = x[x < 0.5]

In [20]: z
Out[20]: array([ 0.03255799,  0.03050498,  0.01951657,  0.04767246,  0.3617409 ])
```

Can something like this be used so that the same thing could be achieved much faster?

Comment: Note that your input is just `np.random.rand(10)`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak : I didn't get you.

Comment: Try `x = np.random.rand(10)` and you'll see that you don't have to call `random()` in a list comp:)

Comment: Yes of course! Thanks :) My real data is not random though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you actually need to do is get the *inverse* of the sorting order of your array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.empty(x.size,dtype=np.int64)
y[x.argsort()] = np.arange(x.size)
```

Example run (in ipython):

```
In [367]: x
Out[367]: 
array([ 0.09139335,  0.29084225,  0.43560987,  0.92334644,  0.09868977,
        0.90202354,  0.80905083,  0.4801967 ,  0.99086213,  0.00933582])

In [368]: y
Out[368]: array([1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 9, 0])
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to get the number of elements *greater* than each corresponding element in `x`, you have to reverse the sorting from ascending to descending. One possible option to do this is to simply swap the construction of the indexing:

```
y_rev = np.empty(x.size,dtype=np.int64)
y_rev[x.argsort()] = np.arange(x.size)[::-1]
```

another, [as @unutbu suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242159/transform-a-set-of-numbers-in-numpy-so-that-each-number-gets-converted-into-a-nu/41242285#comment69684180_41242285), is to map the original array to the new one:

```
y_rev = x.size - y - 1
```

Comment: Or just argsort two times : `x.argsort().argsort()`?

Comment: @Divakar naturally, you're right. But I've never seen this approach:) Would you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: @Divakar:  `y[np.argsort(x)] = np.arange(x.size)` is faster

Comment: @AndrasDeak: To get the desired `y`, the OP would need `y = x.size-y-1`.

Comment: @unutbu I'm still thinking along the lines of your now-deleted comment on the question. Doesn't OP's example output contradict their specification?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Or, the OP could keep the example, but change the text to read, "y would be the number of other elements in x which are **greater** than i".

Comment: @unutbu Look at the last element of `x` in my example: it's the smallest value in `x`, so 0 elements are less than it. Correspondingly, `y` has 0 in that position. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I think your answer is correct. It is consistent with the text of the OP's question, and his `for-loop` code. It is the example that should be changed.

Comment: @unutbu ah OK, thanks for the clarification. I added two versions to do this reverse order (one is yours).

Comment: @Divakar just referred me to this post from http://stackoverflow.com/a/41394980/2336654.  Brilliant method.

Comment: @piRSquared thank you (I'll have to thank him for the publicity;) )

Comment: I added some timings if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
np.searchsorted(np.sort(x),x)
```

Another one mostly based on [`@Andras Deak's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242285/3293881) using `argsort()` -

```
x.argsort().argsort()
```

Sample run -

```
In [359]: x
Out[359]: 
array([ 0.62594394,  0.03255799,  0.7768568 ,  0.03050498,  0.01951657,
        0.04767246,  0.68038553,  0.60036203,  0.3617409 ,  0.80294355])

In [360]: np.searchsorted(np.sort(x),x)
Out[360]: array([6, 2, 8, 1, 0, 3, 7, 5, 4, 9])

In [361]: x.argsort().argsort()
Out[361]: array([6, 2, 8, 1, 0, 3, 7, 5, 4, 9])
```

Comment: I added some timings if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers another solution using boolean indexing could be:

```
sum(x > i for i in x)
```

For your example:

```
In [10]: x
Out[10]: 
array([ 0.62594394,  0.03255799,  0.7768568 ,  0.03050498,  0.01951657,
        0.04767246,  0.68038553,  0.60036203,  0.3617409 ,  0.80294355])

In [10]: y = sum(x > i for i in x)
In [11]: y
Out[10]: array([6, 2, 8, 1, 0, 3, 7, 5, 4, 9])
```

Comment: In a vectorized way : `(x[:,None] > x).sum(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to contribute to this post by providing some testing on @Andras Deak's solution versus `argsort` again.

---

It would appear that `argsort` again is quicker for short arrays.  Simple idea is to evaluate what is the length of array in which we see the balance shift.

I'll define three functions

- `construct` which is Andras Deak's solution
- `argsortagain` which is obvious
- `attempted_optimal` which trades off at `len(a) == 400`

## functions

```
def argsortagain(s):
    return s.argsort()

def construct(s):
    u = np.empty(s.size, dtype=np.int64)
    u[s] = np.arange(s.size)

    return u

def attempted_optimal(s):
    return argsortagain(s) if len(s) < 400 else construct(s)
```

## testing

```
results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.RangeIndex(10, 610, 10, 'len'),
    columns=pd.Index(['construct', 'argsortagain', 'attempted_optimal'], name='function'))

for i in results.index:
    a = np.random.rand(i)
    s = a.argsort()
    for j in results.columns:
        results.set_value(
            i, j,
            timeit(
                '{}(s)'.format(j),
                'from __main__ import {}, s'.format(j),
                number=10000)
        )

results.plot()
```

[image]

## conclusion

`attempted_optimal` does what its supposed to do.  But I'm not sure it's worth it for the marginal benefit gained in a spectrum of array length (sub 400) where it hardly matters.  I'd advocate fully for `constructed` only.

This analysis helped me reach this conclusion.

Comment: Good middleground!