# Speed up Pandas cummin/cummax

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Pandas [`cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin) and [`cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax) functions seem to be really slow for my use case with many groups. How can I speed them up?

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from collections import defaultdict

def cummax(g, v):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(g, columns=['group'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(v)
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

    result = df.groupby('group').cummax()
    result = result.values
    return result


def transform(g, v):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(g, columns=['group'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(v)
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

    result = df.groupby('group').transform(lambda x: x.cummax())
    result = result.values
    return result

def itertuples(g, v):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(g, columns=['group'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(v)
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

    d = defaultdict(list)

    result = [np.nan] * len(g)

    def d_(g, v):
        d[g].append(v)
        if len(d[g]) > 1:
            d[g][-1] = tuple(max(a,b) for (a,b) in zip(d[g][-2], d[g][-1]))
        return d[g][-1]

    for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
        index = row[0]
        result[index] = d_(row[1], row[2:])

    result = np.asarray(result)
    return result

def numpy(g, v):
    d = defaultdict(list)

    result = [np.nan] * len(g)

    def d_(g, v):
        d[g].append(v)
        if len(d[g]) > 1:
            d[g][-1] = np.maximum(d[g][-2], d[g][-1])
        return d[g][-1]

    for i in range(len(g)):
        result[i] = d_(g[i], v[i])

    result = np.asarray(result)
    return result



LENGTH = 100000
g = np.random.randint(low=0, high=LENGTH/2, size=LENGTH)
v = np.random.rand(LENGTH, 40)

%timeit r1 = cummax(g, v)
%timeit r2 = transform(g, v)
%timeit r3 = itertuples(g, v)
%timeit r4 = numpy(g, v)
```

gives

```
1 loop, best of 3: 22.5 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 18.4 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1.56 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 325 ms per loop
```

Do you have any further suggestions how I can improve my code?

**Old**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

LENGTH = 100000

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(low=0, high=LENGTH/2, size=(LENGTH,2)),
    columns=['group', 'value'])

df.groupby('group').cummax()
```

Comment: This is known issue.  See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15048.  Neither `cummin` nor `cummax` are written in the cython, so the performance is slow.

Comment: How about a pure Python implementation without Numpy, Pandas and Cython. Convert it to a list perform all operations and convert it back to Pandas?

Comment: Could you update the timing results with the new `numpy_cummmax` from my post if that worked for you?

Comment: The solution by piRSquared worked best in my aplication. @Divakar: Your solution is certainly nice from a mathematical point of few, but it requires sorting and in my real application I have to process rows in a streaming fashion which makes any sorting unfeasible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We'll use `defaultdict` where the default value will be `-np.inf` because I'll be taking max values and I want a default that everything is greater than.

## solution

Given an array of groups `g` and values to accumulate maximums `v`

```
def pir1(g, v):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: -np.inf)
    result = np.empty(len(g))

    def d_(g, v):
        d[g] = max(d[g], v)
        return d[g]

    for i in range(len(g)):
        result[i] = d_(g[i], v[i])

    return result
```

## demonstration

```
LENGTH = 100000
g = np.random.randint(low=0, high=LENGTH/2, size=LENGTH)
v = np.random.rand(LENGTH)
```

### accuracy

```
vm = pd.DataFrame(dict(group=g, value=v)).groupby('group').value.cummax()
vm.eq(pir1(g, v)).all()

True
```

---

---

---

## Deep Dive

### Compare with Divakar's answer

***headline chart***
[image]

***code***
I took some liberties with Divakar's function to make it accurate.

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

# this is a cythonized version of the next function
def pir1(g, v):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: -np.inf)
    result = np.empty(len(g))

    def d_(g, v):
        d[g] = max(d[g], v)
        return d[g]

    for i in range(len(g)):
        result[i] = d_(g[i], v[i])

    return result
```

---

```
def pir2(g, v):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: -np.inf)
    result = np.empty(len(g))

    def d_(g, v):
        d[g] = max(d[g], v)
        return d[g]

    for i in range(len(g)):
        result[i] = d_(g[i], v[i])

    return result

def argsort_unique(idx):
    # Original idea : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41242285/3293881 
    n = idx.size
    sidx = np.empty(n,dtype=int)
    sidx[idx] = np.arange(n)
    return sidx

def div1(groupby, value): 
    sidx = np.argsort(groupby,kind='mergesort')
    sorted_groupby, sorted_value = groupby[sidx], value[sidx]

    # Get shifts to be used for shifting each group
    mx = sorted_value.max() + 1
    shifts = sorted_groupby * mx

    # Shift and get max accumlate along value col. 
    # Those shifts helping out in keeping cummulative max within each group.
    group_cummaxed = np.maximum.accumulate(shifts + sorted_value) - shifts
    return group_cummaxed[argsort_unique(sidx)]

def div2(groupby, value):
    sidx = np.argsort(groupby, kind='mergesort')
    sorted_groupby, sorted_value = groupby[sidx], value[sidx]
    # factorize groups to integers
    sorted_groupby = np.append(
        0, sorted_groupby[1:] != sorted_groupby[:-1]).cumsum()

    # Get shifts to be used for shifting each group
    mx = sorted_value.max() + 1
    shifts = (sorted_groupby - sorted_groupby.min()) * mx 

    # Shift and get max accumlate along value col. 
    # Those shifts helping out in keeping cummulative max within each group.
    group_cummaxed = np.maximum.accumulate(shifts + sorted_value) - shifts
    return group_cummaxed[argsort_unique(sidx)]
```

***NOTES:***

- It was necessary to factorize the groups in Divakar's solution to generalize it

### accuracy

***integer groups***
Over integer based groups, both `div1` and `div2` produce the same results

```
np.isclose(div1(g, v), pir1(g, v)).all()

True

np.isclose(div2(g, v), pir1(g, v)).all()

True
```

***general groups***
Over string and float based groups `div1` becomes inaccurate but easily fixed

```
g = g / 1000000

np.isclose(div1(g, v), pir1(g, v)).all()

False

np.isclose(div2(g, v), pir1(g, v)).all()

True
```

***time testing***

```
results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index(['pir1', 'pir2', 'div1', 'div2'], name='method'),
    columns=pd.Index(['Large', 'Medium', 'Small'], name='group size'))

size_map = dict(Large=100, Medium=10, Small=1)

from timeit import timeit

for i in results.index:
    for j in results.columns:
        results.set_value(
            i, j,
            timeit(
                '{}(g // size_map[j], v)'.format(i),
                'from __main__ import {}, size_map, g, v, j'.format(i),
                number=100
            )
        )

results
```

[image]

```
results.T.plot.barh()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why this work, but `df.groupby('group').agg(np.maxiumum.accumulate)` does not?

Comment: agg expects a function that reduces dimension. Cumulative maximum does not

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @David I've updated my post.  This is a fast answer.

Comment: @Sorry I am still processing to process floating pt values. So, would `pir1` and `pir2` work with floating pt numbers?

Comment: @Divakar yes, they will.  `div2` has a *very* simple fix to make yours just about as fast as it was and fully generalize it.

Comment: Really sorry, took me a while to process for floating pt ones. Would it be too much of work to update your timings with my updated one? Basically I have one func to switch.

Comment: @Divakar np at all

Answer (score 8):

### Proposed approach

Let's bring some NumPy magic to the table! Well, we will exploit [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html).

**Explanation**

To see how `maximum.accumulate` could help us, let's assume we have the groups lined up sequentially.

Let's consider a sample grouby :

```
grouby column : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Let's consider a sample value :

```
value column  : [3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
```

Using `maximum.accumulate` simply on `value` won't give us the desired output, as we need to do these accumulations only within each group. To do so, one trick would be to offset each group from the group before it.

There could be few methods to do that offsetting work. One easy way would be to offset each group with an offset of max of `value` + 1 more than the previous one. For the sample, that offset would be `6`. So, for the second group, we will add `6`, third one  as `12` and so on. Thus, the modfied `value` would be -

```
value column  : [3, 1, 4, 7, 9, 15, 13, 17, 14, 16]
```

Now,  we can use `maximum.accumulate` and the accumulations would be restricted within each group -

```
value cummaxed: [3, 3, 4, 7, 9, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17])
```

To go back to the original values, subtract the offsets that were added before.

```
value cummaxed: [3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5])
```

That's our desired result!

At the start, we assumed the groups to be sequential. To get the data in that format, we will use `np.argsort(groupby,kind='mergesort')` to get the sorted indices such that it keeps the order for the same numbers and then use these indices to index into `groupby` column.

To account for negative groupby elements, we just need to offset by `max() - min()` rather than just `max()`.

Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
def argsort_unique(idx):
    # Original idea : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41242285/3293881 
    n = idx.size
    sidx = np.empty(n,dtype=int)
    sidx[idx] = np.arange(n)
    return sidx

def numpy_cummmax(groupby, value, factorize_groupby=0): 
    # Inputs : 1D arrays.

    # Get sorted indices keeping the order. Sort groupby and value cols.
    sidx = np.argsort(groupby,kind='mergesort')
    sorted_groupby, sorted_value = groupby[sidx], value[sidx]

    if factorize_groupby==1:
        sf = np.concatenate(([0], np.flatnonzero(sorted_groupby[1:] != \
                            sorted_groupby[:-1])+1, [sorted_groupby.size] ))
        sorted_groupby = np.repeat(np.arange(sf.size-1), sf[1:] - sf[:-1])

    # Get shifts to be used for shifting each group
    mx = sorted_groupby.max()-sorted_groupby.min()+1
    shifts = sorted_groupby*mx

    # Shift and get max accumlate along value col. 
    # Those shifts helping out in keeping cummulative max within each group.
    group_cummaxed = np.maximum.accumulate(shifts + sorted_value) - shifts
    return group_cummaxed[argsort_unique(sidx)]
```

### Runtime test and verification

**Verification**

1) Groupby as ints :

```
In [58]: # Setup with groupby as ints
    ...: LENGTH = 1000
    ...: g = np.random.randint(low=0, high=LENGTH/2, size=LENGTH)
    ...: v = np.random.rand(LENGTH)
    ...: 

In [59]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((g,v)),columns=['group', 'value'])

In [60]: # Verify results
    ...: out1 = df.groupby('group').cummax()
    ...: out2 = numpy_cummmax(df['group'].values, df['value'].values)
    ...: print np.allclose(out1.values.ravel(), out2, atol=1e-5)
    ...: 
True
```

2) Groupby as floats :

```
In [10]: # Setup with groupby as floats
    ...: LENGTH = 100000
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,LENGTH//2,(LENGTH,2))/10.0, \
    ...:                             columns=['group', 'value'])

In [18]: # Verify results
    ...: out1 = df.groupby('group').cummax()
    ...: out2 = numpy_cummmax(df['group'].values, df['value'].values, factorize_groupby=1)
    ...: print np.allclose(out1.values.ravel(), out2, atol=1e-5)
    ...: 
True
```

Timings  -

1) Groupby as ints (same as the setup used for timings in the question) :

```
In [24]: LENGTH = 100000
    ...: g = np.random.randint(0,LENGTH//2,(LENGTH))/10.0
    ...: v = np.random.rand(LENGTH)
    ...: 

In [25]: %timeit numpy(g, v) # Best solution from posted question
1 loops, best of 3: 373 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit pir1(g, v) # @piRSquared's solution-1
1 loops, best of 3: 165 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit pir2(g, v) # @piRSquared's solution-2
1 loops, best of 3: 157 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit numpy_cummmax(g, v)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 ms per loop
```

2) Groupby as floats :

```
In [29]: LENGTH = 100000
    ...: g = np.random.randint(0,LENGTH//2,(LENGTH))/10.0
    ...: v = np.random.rand(LENGTH)
    ...: 

In [30]: %timeit pir1(g, v) # @piRSquared's solution-1
1 loops, best of 3: 157 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit pir2(g, v) # @piRSquared's solution-2
1 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop

In [32]: %timeit numpy_cummmax(g, v, factorize_groupby=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 ms per loop

In [34]: np.allclose(pir1(g, v),numpy_cummmax(g, v, factorize_groupby=1),atol=1e-5)
Out[34]: True
```

Comment: [I See You](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/I_See_You) Divakar.  Simply amazing.  If you navigate my edits, you'll see that I gave this a go.  I couldn't solve the conflicting max accumulation over groups.  You used the same technique you used with 2-D searchsorted.  I've locked the technique away for later.  Thanks again for teaching me something new.

Comment: Also, IIUC: `mx = sorted_value.max()+1; shifts = sorted_value*mx`

Comment: Actually Also, IIUC: `mx = sorted_value.max()+1; shifts = sorted_groups*mx`

Comment: Also, this depends on groups being integers. It breaks down when they are floats that are close. You need to factorize it to be more general. That factorization will eat a bit of time. As is, this is ten times better than my answer. I'm sure factorizing won't eat all that improvement up.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include timing with your solution.

Comment: Few comments before I update.  1) `sorted_group[1:] > sorted_group[:-1]` won't work for groups of type `str`.  Do you supposed `>` is quicker than `!=`?  2) How does your `factorize` method compare to `sorted_groupby = np.append(0, sorted_groupby[1:] != sorted_groupby[:-1]).cumsum()`  3) `np.concatenate(0, bool_array)` automatically switches to `int`

Comment: @piRSquared Well its not meant to work with strings, only floats and ints. Not sure about `>`  being faster than `!=`. I would guess it should be comparable on performance.

Comment: Yes, sure.  But if `!=` is just as efficient over ints and floats as is `>` then leaving it as `!=` now accommodates strings as well for essentially free.

Comment: @piRSquared Ah awesome, thanks for the improvment on generalizing it! Please use `!=` in that case. On - `3) np.concatenate(0, bool_array)`, it won't matter, as we do need ints in the next step as we are doing - `sf[1:] - sf[:-1]`.

Comment: Then I'll leave my timings as is because both versions I test are essentially the same speed.  This answer needs more up-votes.

Comment: @piRSquared That's okay to leave your post as it is then. That `cumsum` was a nice idea too!

Comment: I just realized that this also doesn't account for negatives, `inf` or `nan`.  negatives are easy to incorporate.  `inf`s and `nan`s I think we'll have to track them separately.  Just dumping my thoughts.  I'll post an update when I get to it.

Comment: @piRSquared Good point! Updated for negative elems. Had to add in `-sorted_groupby.min()` there to get `mx`. The runtimes shouldn't change in a huge way, so didn't update those.For Infs and NaNs, we might have to think a bit more.