# Filter outliers from Pandas dataframe from all columns except one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, percentile

Say I have a dataframe with features and labels:

```
f1    f2   label
-1000 -100 1
-5    3    2
0     4    3
1     5    1
3     6    1
1000  100  2
```

I want to filter outliers from columns f1 and f2 to get:

```
f1    f2   label
-5    3    2
0     4    3
1     5    1
3     6    1
```

I know that I can do something like this:

```
data = data[(data > data.quantile(.05)) & ( data < data.quantile(.95))]
```

But 'label' column will also be filtered. How can I avoid filtering some column? I don't want to filter all columns manually because there are dozens of them.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about the following approach:

```
In [306]: x = data.drop('label', 1)

In [307]: x.columns
Out[307]: Index(['f1', 'f2'], dtype='object')

In [308]: data[((x > x.quantile(.05)) & (x < x.quantile(.95))).all(1)]
Out[308]:
   f1  f2  label
1  -5   3      2
2   0   4      3
3   1   5      1
4   3   6      1
```

Comment: btw you might find these useful [cumcount within groups](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41558148/2336654) and [cummax within groups](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41526917/2336654)