# Numpy index of the maximum with reduction - numpy.argmax.reduceat

Tags: numpy, vectorization, reduction, argmax, numpy-ufunc

I have a flat array `b`:

```
a = numpy.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2])
```

And an array `c` of indices marking the start of each "chunk":

```
b = numpy.array([0, 4])
```

I know I can find the maximum in each "chunk" using a reduction:

```
m = numpy.maximum.reduceat(a,b)
>>> array([2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

But... Is there a way to find the index of the maximum `<edit>`within a chunk`</edit>` (like `numpy.argmax`), with vectorized operations (no lists, loops)?

Comment: Deleted my question temporarily because I thought I had an answer: `numpy.argmax(numpy.equal.outer(m,a), axis=1)`, but that doesn't work for examples where the same max occurs in many places...

Comment: For instance on this array: `a = numpy.array([0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2])`, where the same maximum `3` occurs in the two chunks.

Comment: The problem is that `np.maximum` is a `ufunc` with `reduceat` - which effectively iterates through the array, comparing 2 values at a time.  But `np.max` and `np.argmax` are functions that operate on the whole array at once.  They aren't `ufunc`.

Comment: @hpaulj, yes, I'm aware of that. I'm asking if anyone can think of a workaround with the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing the idea from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531751/3293881).

Steps involved :

- Offset all elements in a group by a limit-offset. Sort them globally, thus limiting each group to stay at their positions, but sorting the elements within each group.
- In the sorted array, we would look for the last element, which would be the group max. Their indices would be the argmax after offsetting down for the group lengths.

Thus, a vectorized implementation would be -

```
def numpy_argmax_reduceat(a, b):
    n = a.max()+1  # limit-offset
    grp_count = np.append(b[1:] - b[:-1], a.size - b[-1])
    shift = n*np.repeat(np.arange(grp_count.size), grp_count)
    sortidx = (a+shift).argsort()
    grp_shifted_argmax = np.append(b[1:],a.size)-1
    return sortidx[grp_shifted_argmax] - b
```

As a minor tweak and possibly faster one, we could alternatively create `shift` with `cumsum` and thus have a variation of the earlier approach, like so -

```
def numpy_argmax_reduceat_v2(a, b):
    n = a.max()+1  # limit-offset
    id_arr = np.zeros(a.size,dtype=int)
    id_arr[b[1:]] = 1
    shift = n*id_arr.cumsum()
    sortidx = (a+shift).argsort()
    grp_shifted_argmax = np.append(b[1:],a.size)-1
    return sortidx[grp_shifted_argmax] - b
```

Comment: Both solutions work out nicely in my case, because I already have `shift` from an earlier operation. Nice answer.

Comment: Hey you have answered my questions a few months ago could you take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680199/getting-the-min-and-the-index-of-chunks-numpy-python/67694852#67694852. it is related to this question.