# Getting the minimum indexes with numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, vector

I am trying to get the index values of the function. But I want to get the minimum instead of the maximum values of just like the post: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833740/numpy-index-of-the-maximum-with-reduction-numpy-argmax-reduceat/41835843#41835843). I have tried to convert the function below to work for the minimum values unlike the maximum values to getting the indexes.

Max Values:

```
a = numpy.array([11, 2, 33, 4, 5, 68, 7])
b = numpy.array([0, 4])
min = numpy.minimum.reduceat(a,b)
```

Index Function

```
def numpy_argmin_reduceat_v2(a, b):
    n = a.min()+1  # limit-offset
    id_arr = np.zeros(a.size,dtype=int)
    id_arr[b[1:]] = 1
    shift = n*id_arr.cumsum()
    sortidx = (a+shift).argsort()
    grp_shifted_argmin = np.append(b[1:],a.size)-1
    return sortidx[grp_shifted_argmin] - b
```

Comment: Have you tried numpy.argmin: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the minimum, you need the first item in each group rather than the last. This is accomplished by modifying `grp_shifted_argmin`:

```python
def numpy_argmin_reduceat_v2(a, b):
    n = a.max() + 1  # limit-offset
    id_arr = np.zeros(a.size,dtype=int)
    id_arr[b[1:]] = 1
    shift = n*id_arr.cumsum()
    sortidx = (a+shift).argsort()
    grp_shifted_argmin = b
    return sortidx[grp_shifted_argmin] - b
```

This correctly returns the index of the minimum value within each sublist:

```python
a = numpy.array([11, 2, 33, 4, 5, 68, 7])
b = numpy.array([0, 4])
print(numpy_argmin_reduceat_v2(a, b))
# [1 0]

print([np.argmin(a[b[0]:b[1]]), np.argmin(a[b[1]:])])
# [1, 0]
```

Comment: Sorry I updated the details what if the list was random,. I want to get the minimum between the 2 indexes.

Comment: That's exactly what this function does; see the example I added to the answer.

Comment: Hey you have answered my questions a few months ago could you take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680199/getting-the-min-and-the-index-of-chunks-numpy-python/67694852#67694852. it is related to this question.