# Subdivide values in a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, tensor

I have a PyTorch tensor that contains the labels of some samples.

I want to split each label into `n_groups` groups, introducing new virtual labels.

For example, for the labels:

```py
labels = torch.as_tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=torch.long)
```

One possible solution to subdivide each label into `n_groups=2` is the following:

```py
subdivided_labels = [0, 3, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2]
```

The constraints are the following:

- There is no assumption about the order of the initial labels
- The labels should be well distributed among the groups
- The label ranking should be consistent among different groups, i.e., the first label `0` in the first group should be the first label also in any other group.
- The following should always be true `torch.equal(labels, subdivided_labels % num_classes)`
- It is possible that the number of groups is greater than the number of samples for a given label

---

The following tests should pass for the desired algorithm:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "labels",
    (
        torch.randint(100, size=(50,)),
        torch.arange(100),
        torch.ones(100),
        torch.randint(100, size=(50,)).repeat(4),
        torch.arange(100).repeat(4),
        torch.ones(100).repeat(4),
        torch.randint(100, size=(50,)).repeat_interleave(4),
        torch.arange(100).repeat_interleave(4),
        torch.ones(100).repeat_interleave(4),
    ),
)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("n_groups", (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 50, 150))
def test_subdivide_labels(labels, n_groups):
    subdivided_labels = subdivide_labels(labels, n_groups=n_groups, num_classes=100)
    assert torch.equal(labels, subdivided_labels % 100)

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "labels, n_groups, n_classes, expected_result",
    (
        (
            torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]),
            2,
            3,
            torch.tensor([0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]),
        ),
        (
            torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]),
            2,
            10,
            torch.tensor([0, 10, 1, 11, 2, 12]),
        ),
        (
            torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]),
            1,
            10,
            torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]),
        ),
        (
            torch.tensor([0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1]),
            2,
            3,
            torch.tensor([0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4]),
        ),
        (
            torch.tensor([0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1]),
            30,
            3,
            torch.tensor([0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4]),
        ),
    ),
)
def test_subdivide_labels_with_gt(labels, n_groups, n_classes, expected_result):
    subdivided_labels = subdivide_labels(labels, n_groups=n_groups, num_classes=n_classes)
    assert torch.equal(expected_result, subdivided_labels)
    assert torch.equal(labels, subdivided_labels % n_classes)
```

---

I have a non-vectorized solution:

```py
import torch


def subdivide_labels(labels: torch.Tensor, n_groups: int, num_classes: int) -> torch.Tensor:
    """Divide each label in groups introducing virtual labels.

    Args:
        labels: the tensor containing the labels, each label should be in [0, num_classes)
        n_groups: the number of groups to create for each label
        num_classes: the number of classes

    Returns:
        a tensor with the same shape of labels, but with each label partitioned in n_groups virtual labels
    """
    unique, counts = labels.unique(
        sorted=True,
        return_counts=True,
        return_inverse=False,
    )
    virtual_labels = labels.clone().detach()
    max_range = num_classes * (torch.arange(counts.max()) % n_groups)
    for value, count in zip(unique, counts):
        virtual_labels[labels == value] = max_range[:count] + value
    return virtual_labels

labels = torch.as_tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=torch.long)
subdivide_labels(labels, n_groups=2, num_classes=3)
```

```
tensor([0, 3, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2])
```

Is it possible to vectorize this algorithm?
Alternatively, are there any faster algorithms to perform the same operation?

Comment: I really like the idea to include a `pytest` in the question, but the test passes if the function just `return labels`.

Comment: I didn't realize the preview handled well long code cells, I added other tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation of OP's approach can be vectorized with a grouped cumcount [(`numpy` implementation by @divakar)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40605209/14277722). All tests pass, but the output is slightly different since `argsort` has no 'stable' option in `pytorch`, AFAIK.

```py
def vector_labels(labels, n_groups, num_classes):
    counts = torch.unique(labels, return_counts=True)[1]
    idx = counts.cumsum(0)
    id_arr = torch.ones(idx[-1], dtype=torch.long)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[idx[:-1]] = -counts[:-1] + 1
    rng = id_arr.cumsum(0)[labels.argsort().argsort()] % n_groups
    maxr = torch.arange(n_groups) * num_classes
    return maxr[rng] + labels

labels = torch.arange(100).repeat_interleave(4)
%timeit vector_labels(labels, 2, 100)
%timeit subdivide_labels(labels, 2, 100)
```

Output

```
10000 loops, best of 5: 117 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.6 ms per loop
```

---

This is far from the fastest algorithm. For example a trivial O(n) approach, but only CPU and needs `numba` to be fast with Python.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def numpy_labels(labels, n_groups, num_classes):
    lookup = np.zeros(labels.max() + 1, np.intp)
    res = np.empty_like(labels)
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        res[i] = num_classes * lookup[labels[i]] + labels[i]
        lookup[labels[i]] = lookup[labels[i]] + 1 if lookup[labels[i]] < n_groups-1 else 0

    return res

numpy_labels(labels.numpy(), 20, 100) # compile run
%timeit torch.from_numpy(numpy_labels(labels.numpy(), 20, 100))
```

Output

```
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.63 µs per loop
```

Comment: I confirm it passes all the tests (also the new ones added in the edit)! I just need a bit of time to understand it, thank you for your reply! :)