# Filling a 3D Numpy array with binned values from a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

This is my first post so apologies in advance if I'm missing anything in my description, it doesn't help that I'm quite stuck and lost in what I'm doing, so I'm not sure how to describe it too well.

I'm trying to fill a 3D Numpy array with values from a 2D array without using a for loop.

The 2D numpy array is a collection of points from a point cloud, with each point containing:

[x, y, z, intensity, GPS time]

I have binned them based on their x and y value, and now wish to place them into an array of non empty bins. Therefore the pre-allocated array would be:

`np.zeros(number of non empty bins, longest bin, 5)`

I'm unsure on how to fill this array in a vectorised manner.

For example, given:

```
x_y_bins = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0], [2, 3], [4, 1], [2, 3], [0, 0], [1, 2]])
array_of_points = np.ones((7, 5))  # In real scenario, the first two columns of 1's would relate to the corresponding x_y_bins

unique_pairs, binning_index, count = np.unique(x_y_bins, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True, axis=0)

target_array = np.zeros(len(unique_pairs), max(count), 5)  # (4, 3, 5)
```

The target output would be:

```
target_arr[[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
           [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

I've tried using the binning_index but it just replaces the points in the first row. I've also tried count[binning*_*index] and using that to place them, but that just replaces the points in that index position.

I can do it using a for loop, but that's too slow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate the point, you can use advanced indexing to assign your array of points directly to the target array:

```
import numpy as np

x_y_bins = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0], [2, 3], [4, 1], [2, 3], [0, 0], [1, 2]])
array_of_points = np.arange(1, 36).reshape(7, 5) # Replaced with a more explicit array

unique_pairs, binning_index, count = np.unique(x_y_bins, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True, axis=0)

target_array = np.zeros((len(unique_pairs), max(count), 5), dtype=int)  # (4, 3, 5)
```

Solution:

```
magic_index = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]
target_array[binning_index, magic_index] = array_of_points
```

`target_array`:

```
array([
    [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5], [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10], [26, 27, 28, 29, 30]],
    [[31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0], [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],
    [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],
    [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0], [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]
])
```

The question is, how to create the `magic_index`? Have a look at the bins:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [2, 3], [4, 1], [2, 3], [0, 0], [1, 2]]  # Bins
[     0,      1,      0,      0,      1,      2,      0]  # Magic Index
```

Each element of the magic index is simply the `n-1`th time the corresponding bin appears in the bin list. I don't know of any numpy function that would compute it directly, but you could have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602269/how-to-use-numpy-to-get-the-cumulative-count-by-unique-values-in-linear-time) to get an idea.

In pandas, if you're willing to use it, this is usually done with a `groupby` + `cumcount`! Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

magic_index = pd.Series(binning_index).groupby(binning_index).cumcount().to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll look through the SO post you linked and update when I have an answer. Currently using pandas doesn't offer a speed increase to my work unfortunately, though once I have a solution I'll update with time comparisons. I had hoped I was just missing something in numpy, but it seems that it is indeed going to be a complicated problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Can confirm that using @piRSquared 's cumcount is a very efficient way of finding the 'magic index'. Will try to write some code soon to compare the speeds (not something I've done before so will give it a go when I have time), but for now, thank you very much!

Comment: Super glad you worked it out! Good luck!