# Label a list following the unique elements appearing in it

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, labeling

Given a list of strings such as:

```
foo = \['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'\]
```

How can we label them such that the output would be:

```
output = \['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'A3', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'A4', 'B2', 'C3', 'A5'\]
```

(keeping the order of the original list)

In the following case there are only 3 unique variables to look at, so the first think I tried was looking at the unique elements:

```
import numpy as np

np.unique(foo)

Output = \['A', 'B', 'C'\]
```

But then I get stacked when trying to find the proper loop to reach the desired output.

Comment: For some Numpy-based solutions, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40602269/2954547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure python, take advantage of a dictionary to count the values:

```
foo = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']

d = {}
out = []
for val in foo:
    d[val] = d.get(val, 0)+1
    out.append(f'{val}{d[val]}')
```

If you can use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(foo)
out = s.add(s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)).tolist()
```

Output: `['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'A3', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'A4', 'B3', 'C3', 'A5']`

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
foo_dict = {}
new_foo = []
for item in foo:
    foo_dict[item] = foo_dict.get(item,0)+1
    new_foo.append(f"{item}{foo_dict[item]}")
print(new_foo)
```

[image]

Comment: This is identical to what I already suggested.

Comment: This one is better without Pandas library

Comment: @toyotaSupra there are 2 different approaches in my answer, one in pure python (to which this other answer is identical) and an alternative with pandas

Comment: @mozway , when I starting solving this question there was no answer, when I posted I saw you have also posted an answer several minutes ago, I debated over my head whether or not to delete my answer but then decided it couldnt hurt